# JSON, Array push function does not work with a key defined by a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

My idea is get html data to a json or array from div which has contenteditable  and data-type attribute.
This is what i did [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q93ausht/3/)

I want get all elements with same data-type attribute which looks like:

```
data = {
'title': [{content: 'Value'}],
'content': [{content: 'Value'},{content: 'Value'}]
}
```

But I'm stuck when using push function. Can anybody give me an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `data` from `Array` to `Object`, and add to it `title`, and `content` properties as `Array`, like so

```
var data = {}, i = 1;

$('#get').on('click',function(){
    data = {
        title: [],
        content: []
    };

    $.each($('div[contenteditable="true"]'),function(id, value){
        var key = $(this).data('key'), 
            html = $(this).html();

        data[key].push({content: html});
        i++;
    });

    console.log(data);
});
```

[`Example`](http://jsfiddle.net/q93ausht/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Use `Array.prototype.push` to append elements to **arrays**, not any old object.

For example, in the object in your example...

```
data = {
    'title': [{content: 'Value'}],
    'content': [{content: 'Value'},{content: 'Value'}]
}
```

... you have two arrays:

```
data.title
data.content
```

To push a new object onto the end of `data.title`, you can do this:

```
data.content.push({Content: 'Value'});
```

Now your original `data` object looks like this:

```
{
    'title': [{content: 'Value'}],
    'content': [{content: 'Value'},{content: 'Value'},{content: 'Value'}]
}
```

Comment: Array data  is what i need final, but the way i do pls view jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/q93ausht/3/